# Doctrine DiscriminatorMap clause Where

Tags: doctrine-orm

I need to perform a query with the doctrine in an entity of the type DiscriminatorMap, where my condition where is within the inheritance class

Order

```
<?php
namespace App\Domain;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OrderRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Order
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="orders", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_cliente", referencedColumnName="id_cliente")
     * @JMS\Groups ({"list", "details"})
     * @var Customer
     */
    private $customer;


    /**
     * @return Person|Company
     */
    public function getCustomer(): Customer
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    ....
```

Customer

```
<?php
namespace App\Domain;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"customer" = "Customer", "F" = "Person", "J" = "Company"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="clientes")
 */
class Customer
{
    use TimestampableTrait;
    ....
```

expect

```
$query = $qb->select('p')
                ->from(\App\Domain\Order::class, 'p')
                ->leftJoin('p.customer', 'c')
                ->setMaxResults((int)$params['limit'])
                ->setFirstResult((int)$params['offset']);

$query->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('c.document'));
```

I need to return all sales where the customers are person or company type the document is not null

Comment: Based on the title I think you might be asking about [INSTANCE OF](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#get-all-instances-of-a-specific-type).  No idea what your actual question is asking.

Comment: Looking over the top I believe that this is what I need, I just didn't understand how to use it, there is little in the documentation

I need to get a result like this in sql
``` 
SELECT
 o.id 
FROM
 vendas AS o
 INNER JOIN clientes c ON o.fk_cliente = c.id_cliente
 LEFT JOIN clie_fisica f ON c.id_cliente = f.fk_cliente 
 AND c.tipo = 'F'
 LEFT JOIN clie_juridica j ON c.id_cliente = j.fk_cliente 
 AND c.tipo = 'J' 
WHERE
 COALESCE ( j.cnpj, f.cpf ) IS NOT NULL
 ```